# Mystery problem converting list of dates using datetime

Tags: python, list, date, datetime

```
import datetime

format = "%m/%d/%y"

qq=['7/8/2018', '6/3/2018', '5/28/2018', '5/20/2018', '5/6/2018', '5/5/2018', '3/25/2018', '3/24/2018', '3/23/2018', '3/11/2018', '3/11/2018']

date0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(qq[1],format).date()

print (date0)
```

gives a lot of mistakes. Cannot understand why

Comment: `%y` is for 2 digit years, you want `%Y`.

Comment: *"gives a lot of mistakes"* Please always post the actual mistake/error, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The "%y" format is for 2-digit years.  Try "%Y".

```
import datetime

format="%m/%d/%Y"

qq=['7/8/2018', '6/3/2018', '5/28/2018', 
    '5/20/2018', '5/6/2018', '5/5/2018', 
    '3/25/2018', '3/24/2018', '3/23/2018', 
    '3/11/2018', '3/11/2018']

date0=datetime.datetime.strptime(qq[1],format).date()

print (date0)
```

Gives me:

```
2018-06-03
```

Which is correct for qq[1] (the 2nd element of qq)

Strictly speaking, the date numbers are supposed to be zero-padded, so qq[1] should be '06/03/2016', not '6/3/2016'.  Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior . But it seems to work ok (in Python 3.7.0, for me).